# When does Flask's route decorator execute?

Tags: python, flask, python-decorators

When is `decorator` in Flask's `route` method executed? Specifically, I want to know when `self.add_url_rule()` is executed.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def root_of_app():
    load_root_of_app()
```

Is `add_url_rule` executed when the module containing `root_of_app` is first imported, or when `root_of_app` is first called by a web request?

Here is the source for the `route` function:

```
def route(self, rule, **options):
    def decorator(f):
        endpoint = options.pop('endpoint', None)
        self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
        return f
    return decorator
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can verify this yourself by adding print statements to the `route` decorator.

When `route` is called, it builds a decorator. That decorator is then applied to the view by calling it. Both these happen at import, because importing executes module-level code.

Using `@app.route()` registers the view, it is not deferred until the first request. The *blueprint* version of `route` is deferred until the blueprint is registered on the app, which also happens before the first request.